Runscript.tlu error when opening a second TeXworks windows
I am using TeXlive 2024 on Windows 11. When I open a .tex file using TeXworks where one TeXworks window already exists, an error dialog shows up with the text:

C:\texlive\2024\bin\windows\runscript.tlu: 918 command failed with
exit code: [random 8-digit number] texworks [file path of
the .tex file]

I can still edit the .tex file, but the error message is annoying. How do I fix this problem? Thanks.
